# Core Data and making double from type AnyObject? Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, core-data

I was writing a code for `CoreData`. My datamodel includes name and moneyAmount. Here's the part of the code I have troubles with

```
 do {
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "MoneyData")
        let results = try context.executeFetchRequest(request)
        if results.count > 0 {
            for item in results as! [NSManagedObject] {
                let name = String(item.valueForKey("name"))
                let moneyAmount = item.valueForKey("moneyAmount")
                moneyManager.addMoney(name, moneyAmount: moneyAmount)
            }
        }
    } catch {
        print("There was an error saving data")
    }
```

Now the problem is that my `moneyManager.addMoney` requires `String` and `Double`. However, with this code, the error that I get is:

> Optional Chain has no effect, already produces 'Anyobject?'
>
> Cannot convert value of type AnyObject? to expected argument type 'Double'

I don't really understand what it means by `Anyobject`. I think I should convert anyobject to double to make it work right?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are sure moneyAmount is in Double, you can cast it like let moneyAmount = item.valueForKey("moneyAmount") as! Double

Comment: Have you considered ensuring that moneyAmount is a double? e.g. something like: let moneyAmount = Double(item.valueForKey("moneyAmount"))

Comment: Yes, I did both of them actually, the first one worked. And I have also tried what Dominic has said, however, I am still getting an error then even though it can only be a double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`valueForKey()` returns an object of type `AnyObject` because there's no way of knowing at compile-time what type of object it's referencing.  You can cast to a specific type using `as`.  For example, `moneyAmount as? Double` will result in an object of type `Double?`, either containing the numeric value, or being `nil` if the object wasn't of type `Double`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked now. But what if it's not as? but rather as! cause I know specifically that the type will be Double?

Comment: If you use `as!` instead of `as?`, it means that you are sure that it is gonna be a `Double`, the value won't ever be `nil`. But if it is not a `Double` and you use `as!`, your app is going to crash